# how to make terraform ignore external changes without changing the code itself

Tags: terraform

I'm currently working on a code refactor project for terraform, we want to take all of our old terraform and restructure it so it would be more "developer friendly".
we don't want to do this all at once so we want to move the resources to the new code structure in small batches.

the old code is deployed automatically every day by a pipeline and we want to keep it that way at least until we move everything and we can't really change the original code.
is there a way to move a resource to be controlled by the new code while keeping the old deployment workflow without changing the old code at all? while running the old terraform code after having changed it with the new one we get a message that something changed outside of terraform and it tries to change it back, is there any way to ignore a resource if it has been changed outside of terraform but without touching the old code? something like --ignore-drift or similar?

Comment: Without an example it's hard to tell. There is the `lifecycle` option, but output from the execution would be helpful. Those changes can also happen because of discrepancies between different provider versions etc.

Comment: @MarkoE let's say i manage a bucket with the old code, now i moved it to the new code and changed some of it's configuration. the old code is still running and changing back my new configuration, without changing the old code i want to stop this from happening. maybe change the state? or run the command with a flag?

Comment: Terraform typically assumes that if an object is bound to a resource instance in one Terraform configuration then it will not be managed by any other Terraform configurations or any other systems that aren't Terraform. This is a fundamental assumption that the "desired state" approach relies on and I can't really think of any practical way to avoid it. 

Comment: One _very coarse_ way to go would be to change your automation to create a Terraform plan with the `-refresh=false` option, which will cause Terraform to just assume that what's in the state is a correct representation of the current system. However, that may lead to Terraform creating invalid plans if the remote system has changed in a way that would cause a provider to produce a different plan.

Answer (score 0):

One option to consider is to use targeting: `-target` argument to `terraform apply`. Not sure if you count it as "not modifying the code".

Modify your daily pipeline - i.e. the call(s) to `terraform apply`.
You could start with a `-target` expression (or several of them) which cover the whole configuration and gradually edit the expression to include less and less resources.

Comment: if i could target with a blacklist it may have been viable, unfortunately doing this as it is will be hell to maintain :(

Comment: I see.
Not sure if you are aware you can point to the whole module when using `-target`.